# Infopath from command file in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, infopath

I have a set of commands in a batch (.bat) file, which will open an infopath form.

I have created a link to open that batch file and placed in webpage URL. The Infopath form is opening properly in IE by running the commands in bat file, but the same thing is not working in Chrome or Firefox.

How can I run the batch commands via Infopath in a browser other than Internet Explorer?